# Import numbers from text or Csv file and execute performClick()

Tags: import, openfiledialog

```
Private Sub Button3_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button3.Click

Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Csv Files|*.csv|txt Files|*.txt"
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select a File to import numbers"
Dim convert As String = ""


If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
Using SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim All_lines As String = SR.ReadToEnd
convert = ("Button_" & All_lines)
'Label43.Text = convert
Me.Button_(convert).PerformClick()
End Using 'closes file
End If
End Sub
```

I have a Csv file with numbers:

2
5
6
14
25
36

I want to import a Csv or Txt file with on each new line a number.
My program has corresponding buttons

I am trying to read each line and this is all going fine
I have buttons from Button_0 to Button_36

All I want to do is Me.Button_(imported number).PerformClick()
So with each line I read from the file
I want to create

```
Me.Button_2.PerformClick()
Me.Button_5.PerformClick()
Me.Button_6.PerformClick()
Me.Button_14.PerformClick()
Me.Button_25.PerformClick()
Me.Button_36.PerformClick()

enter code here
```

I am not sure if this is possible
thank you

Comment: I want to mention that every new line in the file has a number

Answer (score 0):

I found it out myself
I use fixed numbers from 0-36 and comparing by each line the number, and for that number do a click on the corresponding button
This does exactly what I needed

If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

```
        Using SR As New System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName)

            Do While SR.Peek() > -1

                Dim Line As Integer = 0
                Line = SR.ReadLine()

                If Line = 0 Then
                    Me.Button_0.PerformClick()

                End If

                If Line = 1 Then
                    Me.Button_1.PerformClick()

                End If

                If Line = 2 Then
                    Me.Button_2.PerformClick()

                End If

                If Line = 3 Then
                    Me.Button_3.PerformClick()

                End If

                If Line = 4 Then
                    Me.Button_4.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 5 Then
                    Me.Button_5.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 6 Then
                    Me.Button_6.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 7 Then
                    Me.Button_7.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 8 Then
                    Me.Button_8.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 9 Then
                    Me.Button_9.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 10 Then
                    Me.Button_10.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 11 Then
                    Me.Button_11.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 12 Then
                    Me.Button_12.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 13 Then
                    Me.Button_13.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 14 Then
                    Me.Button_14.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 15 Then
                    Me.Button_15.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 16 Then
                    Me.Button_16.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 17 Then
                    Me.Button_17.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 18 Then
                    Me.Button_18.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 19 Then
                    Me.Button_19.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 20 Then
                    Me.Button_20.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 21 Then
                    Me.Button_21.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 22 Then
                    Me.Button_22.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 23 Then
                    Me.Button_23.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 24 Then
                    Me.Button_24.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 25 Then
                    Me.Button_25.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 26 Then
                    Me.Button_26.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 27 Then
                    Me.Button_27.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 28 Then
                    Me.Button_28.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 29 Then
                    Me.Button_29.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 30 Then
                    Me.Button_30.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 31 Then
                    Me.Button_31.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 32 Then
                    Me.Button_32.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 33 Then
                    Me.Button_33.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 34 Then
                    Me.Button_34.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 35 Then
                    Me.Button_35.PerformClick()

                End If
                If Line = 36 Then
                    Me.Button_36.PerformClick()

                End If


            Loop
```